# Is there a way to represent route closure actions instead of writing them all in the component shim?

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

I'm using [ember-route-action-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper)

I have a component shim that looks like this:

```
{{component-name model=model 
action1=(route-action "action1") 
action2=(route-action "action2") 
action3=(route-action "action3") 
action4=(route-action "action4") 
action5=(route-action "action5") 
action6=(route-action "action6") 
action7=(route-action "action7") 
action8=(route-action "action8")
action9=(route-action "action9") 
action10=(route-action "action10")
action11=(route-action "action11")
action12=(route-action "action12") 
action13=(route-action "action13") 
action14=(route-action "action14")
}}
```

P.S. Above actions are not using the real action names

There are lots of actions that need to bubble to the route and I don't use controllers in my ember app.

This looks a bit clunky due to too many actions.
Is there a way to represent this same information in another format or write it someplace else in my component `.hbs` file or `.js` file?

Comment: Why are you not using controllers? What is a "component shim"? Why do you have so many actions?

Comment: I avoid using controllers unless there is a need to handle query params. There are just the auto-generated controllers that Ember creates. Reason: "They going away...someday".  By a component shim, I mean the template of a particular route only contains a top-level component and nothing else. More info here: https://emberigniter.com/should-we-use-ember-controllers/

Comment: Even if Controllers manage to get deprecated in the reasonably near future, it doesn't really make sense to avoid them unless you're able to actually use the thing which replaces them. Which you can't, since it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I've heard that routable components will be similar to controllers and we should not avoid using controllers for now if we really don't have to. If you're interested in why, (the concept of controllers isn't going away!) this is the source: https://youtu.be/lP9ap-AKBAM?t=647

Comment: We have recently added a FAQ of "future proofing" applications that should be relevant for this discussion: http://emberjs.com/learn/#faq-future-proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to asking, "why does this function look so clunky?":

```
function(model, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10, arg11, arg12, arg13, arg14) {
    ....
}
```

The answer is: you need to factor your code differently. It's never a good idea to have a function with 15 arguments, and the same goes for components for the exact same reason.

There are several ways to factor this code more clearly. Maybe some of these actions can go on dedicated services instead. Maybe some of them can be grouped into intermediate representations (like a model that has its own actions on it). Probably if you weren't adding an unnecessary template layer by creating a "shim" that doesn't do anything, you could directly pass each of these actions into the relevant child components, which would spread them out into logical places throughout the template.

Without seeing more of your specifics I can't tell what is the appropriate strategy here.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is one shortcut, you can try directly call `route-action` from component without passing all the way down.

```
<button {{action (route-action 'appRouteAction') }}>My-Component button</button>
```

check this [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/aba330d98b7e5a5a1b8b81f2abad7006?numColumns=2&openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)
I am not sure, is this right approach?

Comment: This would work when there is no logic to be performed in the component before bubbling up the action to the route. Do you also know any alternatives that can be written when there IS some logic to be performed in the component first?

Comment: I dont find any alternatives if some logic to be performed in the component first. and I think you need to send actions like how you are doing it right now . there is no shortcut for this IMHO. by the way you can very well use controllers - refer [controllers-are-dead-long-life-controllers](https://locks.svbtle.com/controllers-are-dead-long-life-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

You only pass the action (function) **UP** to route for data manipulation purpose because it is the data owner.

Other non-data related actions should not pass to the route.

Possible solutions,

1. Put all application shared state (not data related) into a `service` and inject it into the component
2. Call model (the data passed into the component) method inside the component instead let the route do the work